# What conditions make this embedding become algebraically closed?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, fields

This question is just out of curiosity.

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the first-order language of theory of rings. Let K and F are two fields such that $K \subseteq F$. If K is existentially closed in F, then we know that there exists a field K* which is elementary extension of  K and F is embedded in K*.

My question is that for which fields is this embedding algebraically closed ? That is, in what the conditions will F be algebraically closed in K* ?

I know that it's not true for $\mathbb{C}$ since we can take F as the function field $\mathbb{C}(t)$ and K* as $\overline{\mathbb{C}(t)}$. But I cannot figure out any conditions to make F algebraically closed in K*. Any comments or suggestions are welcomed. Thank you !

Comment: Does the example mean that you are looking for conditions on $K$ that would guarantee the property holds for all $F$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Exactly.  Lemma 2.3.2 in *On Some classes of Hilbertian fields* by S. Basarab tell us that the property holds in the augmented language $\mathcal{L}_{Rn}$ where $R_n$ is n-ary relation symbol for each positive integer n. But the following axioms $\forall X_0,\ldots,\forall X_n[R_n(X_0,\ldots,X_n) \leftrightarrow (\exists Y)X_0+X_1Y+\cdots+X_nY^n=0] $ should be added to the axioms of fields in order to interpret $R_n$ as relation on any field K for all n. So I am seeking any condition in the ordinary language of theory of rings.